Variable time execution for INSERT/UPDATE
I do an INSERT/UPDATE in a table who has around 1+ million rows in MySQL 8.0. I don't know why I have different execution times for the same data to insert.
For example, I try to insert exactly the same row during my tests and I measure one time 40 milliseconds and an other time 2 seconds.
There are no other queries running at the same time except mine.
How is it possible ?
Additional informations
OS : Microsoft Windows Server 2019 Standard (64 bits)
RAM : 16 GB
4 cores
2 disks - 120 GB x2, don't know if it's NVME or SSD (it's not mine)
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;

Result : 203
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;

Result : https://justpaste.it/e5ek0
SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;

Result : https://justpaste.it/5sg1i
SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;

Result : https://justpaste.it/63gdx
SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;

Result : https://justpaste.it/fot5h
